# Match strings between keywords and earliest "," character

Tags: javascript, regex

I need the regex to match specific keywords and the nearest "," character. here is my example string:

```
ersion: V3  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aa@example.com, GIVENNAME=Blob, SURNAME=Bloby, CN=B dddddddddddd, O=sd, C=IR  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits  modulus
```

now I need to match the words between EMAILADDRESS and the next , which would be "aa@example.com" (for the words between these two points there is no limitation they could be any characters. what would be the appropriate regex for this?

Comment: You should've included your attempts in your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using capturing group:

```
var str = 'ersion: V3  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aa@example.com, GIVENNAME=Blob, SURNAME=Bloby, CN=B dddddddddddd, O=sd, C=IR  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits  modulus'
str.match(/EMAILADDRESS=([^,]+)/i)[1]
// => "aa@example.com"
```

- `[^,]` match any character exception `,`.

Comment: What would be the solution if I need to match the keyword ignoring case? for example emailaddress ?

Comment: @user435245, Add `i` flag (Ignore case) at the end of the regular expression literal. I modified the code to include the `i` flag.

Comment: What is the simillar expression in java?

Comment: @user435245, Please post another question. As far as I know, the regular expression itself `EMAILADDRESS=([^,]+)` is same except `i` flag. (Java does not have regular expression literal). Use [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) or use `(?i)EMAILADDRESS=([^,]+)`. You need to escape `\` if there is ...

Comment: I meant escaping backslash(\\) in the last comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness,

```
var data = "version: V3  Subject: EMAILADDRESS=aa@example.com...", result = [];
data.split(",").forEach(function(currentItem) {
    var idx = currentItem.indexOf("EMAILADDRESS=");
    if (idx !== -1) {
        result.push(currentItem.split("EMAILADDRESS=", 1)[1]);
    }
});

console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
[ 'aa@example.com' ]
```

Comment: what is 'len' variable for? seems redundant.

Comment: @MichałRybak Oops. I had a different idea in my mind while writing this answer... I forgot to delete `len`. Thanks :)